# I accidentally deleted dconf-cli, and GRUB shows no menu

Tags: boot, grub2, dconf

I know I'm an idiot. Long story short, thinking I was simply deleting the dconf-editor, I ran from terminal

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove dconf-cli
```

and now my Dell XPS 13 with 20.04 won't boot. When I boot to GRUB, instead of the normal boot menu showing up giving me an option to boot in recovery mode, all I see is:

```
GNU GRUB version 2.04

Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TABlists possible device or file completions.
```

Am I just going to need to backup then reinstall from my USB?

Comment: I'm not an expert, but from my experience once you've gotten to that stage, unless you have a very detailed workflow on you computer which is going to take forever to set back up, it will be much faster simply to backup and reinstall.

Comment: Yeah, you're totally right. That's what I ended up doing...won't be making that mistake again.